# I'm creating a locat TS Library for our project, but the TSDoc isn't displayed in the IDE

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, webstorm, tsc

I'm writing a small TypeScript library to be used by multiple sub-systems.

In a different project I linked to the library using npm, but WebStorm only displays the TSDoc for methods, not for classes.

package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "shared-utilities",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A package description...",
  "main": "src/index.ts",
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "npm run build",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "files": [
    "./dist"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2015",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

The TSDoc of a class is not displayed:

[image: Class TsDoc]

While the TsDoc of a method is displayed:

[image: Method TsDoc]

Additionally, WebStorm doesn't import classes automatically when using them, like it does with other libraries. I would have to import it manually.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: First, "TSDoc is a proposal to standardize the doc comments used in TypeScript code, so that different tools can extract content without getting confused by each other's markup. " (typedoc site) Second, without more information it is impossible to say anything more.